# JavaScript Recurring Appointments Library

Tags: javascript, calendar, recurring, appointment

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that can calculate recurring appointments. Something that can handle things like "every 2nd Wednesday". The solution needs to be JavaScript and client side only. I don't need a calendar, just something that can do the date recurring appointment calculations. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you trying to schedule something using this ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to do some light weight scheduling. I've got some js code I wrote 10 years ago lying around. Kind of thought something might have turned up by now. It's a surprising hard problem to get right. Some events like election day odd (the first Tuesday after the first Monday).

Answer (score 1):

There is a JavaScript implementation of `strtotime()` [**over on phpjs.org**](http://phpjs.org/functions/strtotime:554). It seems to be able to do calculations like

```
 strtotime('+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds', 1129633200);
```

based on UNIX timestamps.

You could find the first wednesday using `strtotime("next wednesday")` (If that's implemented), and then count on using `strtotime("+2 weeks");`.

I 'm not sure what to think about phpjs in general and I haven't worked with it, but maybe that function cuts it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the answers of this question: [How to check/calculate the week-day count (using Date functions) using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028061/how-to-check-calculate-the-week-day-count-using-date-functions-using-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I made a javascript / typescript library for handling complex recurring schedules: [rSchedule](https://gitlab.com/john.carroll.p/rschedule)

I was previously using a javascript library called [rrule](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule), but ended up making my own library so that I could handle timezones as well as recurring schedules made up of recurring schedules. I also wanted to make use of the latest es6 features (i.e. generators).